# Sharing integration test in multi module Maven project

Tags: java, spring, maven, kotlin

Consider a Maven project with three modules `Common`, `ServiceA`, `ServiceB` where both services depend on `Common` and produce a war that is deployed as separate microservice. For each service I'd like to run an integration test, that checks the service exposes a healthcheck endpoint on `/health` path.

```kotlin
@Test
open fun testHealthCheck() {
    // implicitly asserts that response status is 200
    perform("/health", method = RequestMethod.GET)
}
```

The only solution I could come up with is to duplicate this test into test packages of each service. However, that's not very DRY. I'd like this integration test to be defined in a single place (preferably in the `Common` module) but to be run during the integration tests phase of each service.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: I would suggest to run the integration tests either within the appropriate service the IT's for ServiceA in ServiceA or completely separate cause an IT's has usually other needs for dependencies...

Comment: @khmarbaise Well, yeah. But how do I do that? PLease, see my question again, a tried to make it clearer.

Comment: Is this a spring or spring boot application ?

Comment: @khmarbaise It's good ol' Spring. .)

Comment: If you had a complicated logic - I think the best solution would be to put the logic into some shared class and then create a test in each module which invokes that shared class. So you have N tests that invoke 1 method with assertions. But in your case you'd better duplicate the test multiple times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to achive that. Both of that have pros and cons.

## Unpack shared tests

Maven can attach multiple artifacts to each modules (e.g. sources or tests, etc.).
First step is to attach test classes of the shared module.

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- ... -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <!-- ... -->
</build>
```

After this it's easy to use in an other project as a dependency:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.zforgo.stackoverflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>shared-tests</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

In the dependent project or module shared tests should unpack.

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- ... -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>share-tests</id>
                    <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>io.github.zforgo.stackoverflow</groupId>
                                <artifactId>shared-tests</artifactId>
                                <version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                                <classifier>tests</classifier>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <!-- ... -->
</build>
```

**NOTE**: the `ArtifactItem` ignores `type` attribute  so the `classifier` attribute should used instead of `type`. There is an issue in `maven-dependency-plugin` issue tracking system. [MDEP-732](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-732)

During unit or integration test phase the unpacked classes will run.

```sh
[INFO] ---------------< io.github.zforgo.stackoverflow:project >---------------
[INFO] Building project 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT                                    [3/3]
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.1.2:unpack (share-tests) @ project ---
[INFO] Configured Artifact: io.github.zforgo.stackoverflow:shared-tests:tests:0.2.0-SNAPSHOT:jar
[INFO] Unpacking /work/source/stackoverflow/junit-test-sharing/multimodule-test-sharing/shared-tests/target/shared-tests-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar to /work/source/stackoverflow/junit-test-sharing/multimodule-test-sharing/project/target/test-classes with includes "" and excludes ""
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M5:test (default-test) @ project ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running io.github.zforgo.stackoverflow.shared.SharedUnitTest
>>>> THIS IS A SHARED UNIT TEST <<<<
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.044 s - in io.github.zforgo.stackoverflow.shared.SharedUnitTest
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0-M5:integration-test (default) @ project ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running io.github.zforgo.stackoverflow.shared.SharedIntegrationTestIT
>>>> THIS IS A SHARED INTEGRATION TEST <<<<
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.005 s - in io.github.zforgo.stackoverflow.shared.SharedIntegrationTestIT
```

| Pros | Cons |
| --- | --- |
| Both unit and integration tests shared in one step. | Needs a workaround cause of [MDEP-732](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-732) |
| Shared tests will be packed into dependent artifact. Prevent changes. | Class duplication makes dependent test-jar bigger unnecessarily. |
| Inclusion and exclusion supported during unpack. |  |

## Using failsafe and surefire plugins' `<dependenciesToScan>` attribute (recommended)

First of all I'd like to say thanks to @khmarbaise for suggestion.

Fortunately both `maven-surefire-plugin` and `maven-failsafe-plugin` has `<dependenciesToScan>` configuration attribute. All those listed dependencies will be scanned for test classes to include and run.
**NOTE** Listed artifacts must be `<dependency>` elements in the dependent project or module.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>io.github.zforgo.stackoverflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>shared-tests-aggregator</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>project</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>shared-tests</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <dependenciesToScan>
                        <dependency>${project.groupId}:shared-tests:test-jar</dependency>
                    </dependenciesToScan>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <dependenciesToScan>
                                <dependency>${project.groupId}:shared-tests:test-jar</dependency>
                            </dependenciesToScan>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**NOTE**: `maven-failsafe-plugin:integration-test` goal will report false error messages to console if the same package is missing in the dependent project.

```sh
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-failsafe-plugin:3.0.0-M5:integration-test (default) @ project ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] WARNING: package io.github.zforgo.stackoverflow.shared not in project
[INFO] Running io.github.zforgo.stackoverflow.shared.SharedIntegrationTestIT
>>>> THIS IS A SHARED INTEGRATION TEST <<<<
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.034 s - in io.github.zforgo.stackoverflow.shared.SharedIntegrationTestIT
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO]
```

| Pros | Cons |
| --- | --- |
| Easy to separate unit- and integration test sharing | Configuration must be duplicated when unit- and integration tests are shared |
| Shared tests wont copied, no class duplication | Delusive [ERROR] messages in logs but build is success. |
| Responsible plugins will handle dependent test classes | Possible configuration changes time to time, version to version. Always read the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#dependenciesToScan) |

## Using `build-helper-maven-plugin`

This MojoHaus plugin allows to use multiple source or test-source directories in one module or project.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>io.github.zforgo.stackoverflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>shared-tests</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.0-SHAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.zforgo.stackoverflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>shared-test</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.0-SHAPSHOT</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>${project.parent.basedir}/shared-test/src/test/java/com/example/demo/shared</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

| Pros | Cons |
| --- | --- |
|  | Works only with local folders. External artifacts not supported. |
|  | Folders are hardcoded. Maintenance issues. |

In short there are more possibilities to share tests between projects and modules but it's your turn to chose the best one.

Comment: Thanks for this exhaustive answer!

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a new Maven module specifically for integration testing? This module can then depend on both `ServiceA` and `ServiceB`.
Your tests can then be run as part of the integration tests phase of this new module.

You may want to use the Maven failsafe plugin for integration tests. This allows integration tests to run from a separate goal. The reason for doing that would be for Continuous Integration tools such as Jenkins, where you would want unit tests to run, but not integration tests because, for example, they depend on an external web service running. If that service was not running, your CI build would fail.

Comment: "_you'll need the Maven failsafe plugin for integration tests to run via Maven_" - why? I can easily write any type of test and run it with surefire. I could include/exclude them via properties/profiles.

Comment: Fair enough, I've edited the answer to try and clarify this.